# c# wsdl The signature or decryption was invalid

Tags: c#, wsdl

We have a third party client that has a web service that we call from our software after a certain transaction. They already provided us the url as well as the certificate for validation. Unfortunately every time we call the URL it gives us this error

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The signature or decryption was invalid

This is my firstime integrating with soap and I don't know if the error is coming from our end. I hope you can give incites what I've missed. I already googled for 3 for an answer but no luck.

Comment: It's a Java error, so it's from their end. SOAP interoperability between .NET and Java is tricky to get right depending on the configuration on both sides, but there are plenty of debugging options. Which have you tried?

Comment: I only tried basic debugging from a test unit that's where I encounter this error. Is there any option to debug the configurations?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem, could you solve it?